# Multiple routes in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want multiple routes in my application and i am using following code.

```
     routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Custom",
        url: "{lang}/{action}/{id}/{Title}/{type}",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Main",
            action = "Default",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional,
            Title = UrlParameter.Optional,
            lang = "en",
            type = UrlParameter.Optional
        }
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Admin",
            action = "Login",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        }
    );
```

**Problem** 
This works fine for `/en/Default/id/title/type` here `default` is my action name.
When is user `/Admin/Login` then its throw server error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine in both conditions.

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Custom",
                "{lang}/{action}/{id}/{Title}/{type}",
                new
                {
                    controller = "Main",
                    action = "Default",
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    Title = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    lang = "en",
                    type = UrlParameter.Optional
                }, new { lang = @"(en)|(hi)|(es)" }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              new
              {
                  controller = "Main",
                  action = "Default",
                  id = UrlParameter.Optional
              }
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use route constraint for this.

Possibly following. It is not tested but route constraint solve your problem.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Custom",
        url: "{lang}/{action}/{id}/{Title}/{type}",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Main",
            action = "Default",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional,
            Title = UrlParameter.Optional,
            lang = "en",
            type = UrlParameter.Optional
        },
        new { lang= "[en|us]"}
       }
```

Comment: We can't add `,new { lang= "[en|us]"}` in this way.

Comment: Try to move default route above.